# Unity WebApps API not available on load in Chromium

Tags: unity, chromium, webapps

I have my website setting up the unity webapp integration on load. In contrast to Firefox, Chromium hasn't the API available immediately after loading the page.
Is there any best practice how to wait for the API to become available or should I just recheck after a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below ([from here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/131152518/launcher-action.html)) shows the event `unity-webapps-api-ready` will fire when the API is available. I'm not sure where this is officially documented, but it seems to work for me.

```
function onApiReady() {
    Unity = external.getUnityObject(1.0); 
    Unity.init({name: "Unity Web Tutorial",
        iconUrl: "http://www.ubuntu.com/tutorialIcon.png",
        onInit: unityReady});
}

if (navigator.userAgent.search('Chromium') >= 0) {
    // Wait until WebApps API is available
    document.addEventListener('unity-webapps-api-ready', onApiReady);
} else {
    onApiReady();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I've been searching for. I haven't found any documentation on that.